# C include error multiple definition error

Tags: c, include

I'm encountering a classic error but still don't get why it occurs...

Below is the simplified explanation
Apparently I have two C files main.c and support.c

in support.c i have one function void bla(int input);

in main.c i have several functions using bla from support.c, and i included

```
#include<support.c>
```

at the top of main.c

However I cannot compile the project because of the error multiple definition of bla, first defined here (eclipse points to the definition of bla in support.c)

I know that optimally I would have to create header file support.h and gives prototype extern void bla(int input) there, but for this I have to include the .c file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that I have to make .h files. But I'm doing an assignment and somehow the teacher asks me to include the .c file instead of creating .h files. I don't know if there is any possible way to deal with this.

Comment: I hope the goal of the assignment is to find out that is a bad idea to `#include` .c files...

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor will copy the contents of `support.c`, and paste it to `main.c` to replace the line `#include<support.c>`. So there are two definition of the function `bla`, one in `support.c`, the other in `main.c`.

The solution is, don't include an source file. Put the **declarations** of functions that you want to export in a header file `support.h`, and include the header file in `main.c`:

```
#include "support.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't include source files into other source files. Instead you make a header file (with the extension `.h`) that contains *declarations* of functions, i.e. function prototypes. Then you build both source files separately, and link them together to form the final executable.

So a header file `support.h` like

```
#ifndef SUPPORT_H
#define SUPPORT_H

void blah(void);

#endif
```

(The preprocessor `#ifdef`/`#define`/`#endif` things are for [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), to protect from multiple inclusion in the same source file.)

Then the `support.c` source file

```
#include "support.h"

void blah(void)
{
    /* Some code here... */
}
```

And finally the `main.c` source file

```
#include "support.h"

int main(void)
{
    blah();
    return 0;
}
```

If you have an IDE (like Visual  Studio) if you add these files to your project the IDE will make sure everything is built and linked properly. If you're compiling on the command line, compile each source file into an object file (usually using an option like `-c` (used for GCC and clang)) and then link the two object files together to create the executable.

---

Command line example with GCC:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
$ gcc -Wall -c support.c -o support.o
$ gcc main.o support.o -o my_program
```

The above three commands will first compile the source files into object files, and then link them together.

Answer (score 1):

What compiler are you using?

When compiling, make sure you do this:

```
gcc main.c support.c -o yourProgram
```